# Why are C++ type expressions not interpreted left to right?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer

For example, I usually read `int const * const *` backwards as "pointer to a constant pointer to a constant integer". Why doesn't C++ expect it as left to right like `* const * const int`. Would this cause any compatibility issues with other C++ language features if the language was changed to this style?

I'm aware that a qualifier like const can appear on any side of the base type. The side for the asterisks and subsequent consts is what I'm really after.

Comment: What other languages are you talking about? and you know that `int const * != int *const` don't you?

Comment: `const int *` (pointer to a constant int) is not the same than `int * const`  (const pointer to an int).

Comment: I guess there is no technical answer, the language was simply designed this way.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo in fact Kernighan and Ritchie explained their design choice in the first book ever written on C language.  And C++ inherited this syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rationale behind the pointer syntax is explained is best explained by  Kernighan & Ritchie themselves ( K&R, first edition, page 90):

> int *px; is intended as a mnemonic: it says that the combination *px
>   is an int, that is if px occurs in the context *px it is equivalent to
>   avariable of type int.  In effect **the syntax of the declaration** for a
>   variable **mimics the syntax of the expression in which the variable may
>   appear.**

Additional remarks related to your hypothetical inverted syntax:

- the standard syntax allows to mix pointers and non pointers: `int a,*px, atoi(char*);` which wouldn't be possible in your inverted syntax.
- this standard syntax allows to combine pointers and arrays in a consistent way:  `char *s[10]` is an array of 10 pointers to char.  What would be your inverted syntax for this:  `[10]* char s` ?  `* char s[10]` ? And would it stay consisten if a second dimension would be added to the array ?
- finally, how would you consitently declare a function pointer like `char *(*f)(int)` in your inverted syntax ?

Answer (score 3):

It ultimately comes from the fact that `*` is, unfortunately, a prefix operator, probably deriving from B, BCPL, etc. Compare Pascal where the defererence operator is `^` and is postfix. If the C `*` operator had been postfix:

- the pointer-to-function syntax would have been comprehensible, not requiring parentheses
- the `->` operator wouldn't have been necessary: instead you would just write `ptr*.member`.

Comment: You are talking about the dereference operator `*`, while OP is asking about  pointer declaration syntax.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo The Standard does say: "The declarators specify the names of these entities and (optionally) modify the type of the specifiers with operators such as * (pointer to) ..." So while they're different, he doesn't necessarily have to change his answer.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo No, he is asking about 'type expressions', but in any case you are introducing a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Those are intentionally similar, see Christophe's answer. A postfix syntax `p*` would have lead to the declaration form `int p*` just as postfix `arr[N]` expressions are mirrored in postfix declarations `int arr[10]`.

Comment: The distinction does exist, taking from your example of Pascal, compare how pointers are declared (prefix to the type) and how pointers are dereferenced (postfix to the identifier). The fact that the two expressions in C/C++ happen to share the same syntax is a design choice and that should be stressed, not taken for granted. @Cristophe got the right answer imho. Also, I don't see how the two examples are related to the question.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo The distinction exists in Pascal. It does not exist in C. You're just creating confusion where none exists. To address your specific comment, it doesn't make any difference whether he is 'talking about defererence operators' or 'asking pointer declaration syntax'. Please stop it.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from C, where types are written to mimic the value type of the expressions with the same decorations around it.  What is the type of the expression `*p` ?

Answer (score 0):

The star is assigned to the variable. A pointer is not a special type, but a special behavior of a variable.
So

```
int *a, b;
```

would mean, that a is a pointer to an integer, while b is just integer.
To have both an integer would be:

```
int *a, *b;
```

With your suggestion, this understanding would be gone. But you can use smart pointers, introduced in C++11.

Comment: A pointer very much is a special type: `using pi = int* ;` defines `pi` as the pointer-to-int type. No variable in sight there.